# How to manage the legend for many plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I handle this issue

```
clear all; close all; clc;
r = 0:5;
zeta = 0:0.1:1;
for i = 1:size(zeta(:))
    for j = 1:size(r(:))
    X(i,j) = sqrt((1+(2*zeta(i)*r(j))^2)/((1-r(j)^2)^2+ (2*zeta(i)*r(j))^2));
    end
    plot(r,X);
    xlabel('r = \omega/\omega_n');
    ylabel('M = \frac{X}{Y}');
    hold all
    grid
    [~,~,~,current_entries] = legend;
    legend([current_entries {sprintf('\zeta = %i',zeta(i))}]);
end
figure
plot(r,X)
grid
```

The `hold all` command doesn't seem to be working properly. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your sampling rate of 1 step is misleading for zeta = 0, consider increasing the sampling rate and using a semilog scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to set the [`DisplayName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/specify-legend-descriptions-during-line-creation.html?searchHighlight=displayname) property of the plot. Then when you create the `legend`, the labels will automatically be populated.

```
plot(r, X, 'DisplayName', 'name')
```

Also, the string that you were passing to `sprintf` for your legends needs to be escaped becuase `sprintf` thinks that `\z` is a control character.

```
plot(r, X, 'DisplayName', sprintf('\\zeta = %0.1f',zeta(k)))
```

Also, `hold on` is recommended over `hold all`. Also, it is best practice to specify the axes handle when calling `hold` to ensure that it is applied to the current axes.

```
hold(hax, 'on')
```

So if we incorporate these changes into your plotting code (along with [@R.Falque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562693/r-falque)'s idea to use `semilogy`)

```
r = 0:0.001:5;
zeta = 0:0.1:1;

hax = axes();

colors = hsv(numel(zeta));

for k = 1:numel(zeta)
    X = sqrt((1 + (2 * zeta(k) * r).^2) ./ ((1-r.^2).^2+ (2*zeta(k)*r).^2));
    semilogy(r, X, ...
               'DisplayName', sprintf('\\zeta = %0.1f',zeta(k)), ...
               'Color', colors(k,:));
    hold(hax, 'on')
end

grid(hax, 'on')

xlabel(hax, 'r = \omega/\omega_n', 'Interpreter', 'tex');
ylabel(hax, 'M = $\displaystyle\frac{X}{Y}$', 'Interpreter', 'latex');

L = legend('show');
```

[image]

Comment: I think you modified the value of `X`, I can't find how. but from the initial equation for zeta = 1, all the values where above one. Nice trick for the colours btw!

Comment: Is there anyway to make `\zeta=0.1 instead of zeta=1.000000e-1`

Comment: @AlFagera updated. I updated the [format specifier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0ybtd) for `sprintf` to use a single decimal point (`%0.1f`)

Comment: Okay, I think I should use r=0:0.001:5; as in other answer, which make more sense.

Comment: @AlFagera Makes sense. I was just modelling after what you had. If you plug it in it will work just fine with my code.

Comment: @Suever Fine, I already did. If you've a time you may need to update your figure in the answer, with more compact zeta (0.1, ... etc),just for the public utility .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cells array as follow:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
r = 0:0.001:5;
zeta = 0:0.1:1;

figure;
for i = 1:length(zeta)
    for j = 1:length(r)
        X(j) = sqrt((1+(2*zeta(i)*r(j))^2)/((1-r(j)^2)^2+ (2*zeta(i)*r(j))^2));
    end
    semilogy(r,X);
    hold on
    legend_string{i} = ['\zeta = ', num2str(zeta(i))];
end
hold off

grid
xlabel('r = \omega/\omega_n');
ylabel('M = $\frac{X}{Y}$','Interpreter', 'Latex');

legend(legend_string);
```

Note that you have an error in the `X` definition (corrected from `X(i,j)` to `X(j)`).

[image]